# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no property 'polar'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

I'm having troubles to plot a spyder graph, I'm making it on pyside with matplotlib
Here is my class(widget in a widget):

```
# IMPORT PYSIDE CORE
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from pyside_core import *

# IMPORT MODULES
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from math import pi

# IMPORT DICTS
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from gui.core.dicts import util_lists


# PY SPYDER WIDGET
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PySpyderWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(
            self,
            language,
            parent=None,
            bg_two="#343b48",
            dark_three="#21252d",
            axis_color="#f5f6f9",
            color_title="#dce1ec",
            line_color="#3f6fd1"
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.language = language

        self.spyder_chart = _CustomSpyder(
            self,
            language=self.language,
            bg_two=bg_two,
            dark_three=dark_three,
            axis_color=axis_color,
            color_title=color_title,
            line_color=line_color
        )

        self.principal_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.principal_layout.addWidget(self.spyder_chart)


class _CustomSpyder(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(
            self,
            parent,
            bg_two,
            dark_three,
            axis_color,
            color_title,
            line_color
    ):
        fig1, self.ax = plt.subplots(111, polar=True, dpi=100)
        super().__init__(fig1)
        # COLORS
        self.bg_two = bg_two
        self.dark_three = dark_three
        self.axis_color = axis_color
        self.color_title = color_title
        self.line_color = line_color

        self._parent = parent
        self._data = None
        self.setParent(parent)

    def set_data(self, data):
        if self._data is not None:
            self._data = pd.concat([self._data, data], axis=0)
        else:
            self._data = data

    def set_chart(self, players, opts):
        angles = [n / float(len(opts)) * 2 * pi for n in range(len(opts))]
        angles += angles[:1]
        if self._data is not None:
            column_index_name = self._data.columns[0]
            tmp_df = self._data[self._data[column_index_name].isin(players)]
            tmp_df = tmp_df.loc[:, opts]
            tmp_df = tmp_df.set_index(column_index_name)
            # EXTRACT VALUES FOR PLAYER 1
            values1 = tmp_df.iloc[0].tolist()
            values1 += values1[:1]
            # EXTRACT VALUES FOR PLAYER 2
            values2 = tmp_df.iloc[1].tolist()
            values2 += values2[:1]
            plt.xticks(angles[:-1], opts)
            # FILL FOR PLAYER 1
            self.ax.plot(angles, values1)
            self.ax.fill(angles, values1, 'teal', alpha=0.1)
            # FILL FOR PLAYER 2
            self.ax.plot(angles, values2)
            self.ax.fill(angles, values2, 'red', alpha=0.1)

            plt.draw()

        else:
            self.ax.clear()
```

and the error is like the title

**AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no property 'polar'**

in line

```
fig1, self.ax = plt.subplots(111, polar=True, dpi=100)
```

I guess the formatting on that line is not correct or maybe I should do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you pass the "polar" keyword in subplot_kw ? See here : https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

As for the error in itself, nor subplots nor figure have a "polar" argument, that's what the error message is telling you (you can see in the link above that extra keyword arguments passed to pyplot.subplots get passed to the pyplot.figure call).